# How can I form a string containing numbers from 0 to n

Tags: java, string, java-stream

For e.g. when `n = 5`, I need to generate a string `"012345"`.

I could do it by running a `for` loop from `0` to `n` and appending numbers to a string.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    s += i;
}
```

Is there a simple way of doing it without the `for` loop? Perhaps using streams?

Comment: 0 to n numbers or 0 to 9 inclusive digits. (i.e. max of 10 characters)?

Comment: `String s="";for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)s+=i;`. I removed the spaces to make it more compact if you want. Don't use streams at all costs, loops are here for a reason you know...

Comment: I agree streams is an inferior way to go.  But you **should** use StringBuilder.

Comment: @WJS true. Though until Java 8 StringBuilder was used internally when using `+=` on Strings. That changed in more recent versions of Java for a better mechanism which name I forgot... (see also a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) on that topic)

Comment: @Matthieu it doesn’t matter whether the compiler generated code uses `StringBuilder` or a different technique. What matters, is that your `+=`  inside a loop will create a complete `String` in each iteration, leading to the O(n²) time complexity that you should avoid. Regardless of the Java version, the compiler will not transform the loop. Look the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/2711488), right below the one you’ve linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IntStream` and `StringBuilder`:

```
int n = 5;
String string = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n)
     .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
     .toString();
```

However, for this particular case it's better to use a for-loop with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You could use `collect(Collectors.joining())` and have the same output

Comment: Yes, but first you need to `mapToObj` as this collector is not available for `IntStream`.

Comment: There is no need to use streams.  It is inferior.  If you don't believe me, time it.  Change to a loop and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Well, you could use `boxed` before calling `collect`

Comment: @WJS Notice the tag is [tag:java-stream] and the question might be a part of something bigger where Streams are justified. While I agree the for-loop is more suitable for a prticular case, I dont find a reason to persuade the OP that it's the only correct solution. Moreover the OP might just want to learn and explore the possibilies of the Stream AP. I can add a note about the for-loop approach which is definetly more suitable to this particular case, but I still dont u derstand a reason behind the downvote. Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis  Point taken.  Downvote removed.

Comment: `String string = new String(IntStream.rangeClosed('1', '1'+n).toArray(), 0, n);`

Comment: @Holger: Pretty neat! But I got `new String(...)` associated with that the String will not be pooled in the String pool. Out of curiosity, do you have a comment justifying this approach?

Comment: You should never expect a newly constructed string to be in the pool. That applies to the result of your approach as well (as any result of calling `toString` on a `StringBuilder`). Since putting a string into the pool is an expensive operation, that is not a disadvantage. The only strings that are guaranteed to be pooled, are compile time constants and the result of calling `intern()` (but the latter should be used judiciously, as said, adding to the pool is not cheap). Use whatever is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do this is the way you're already done it in your Question using a loop. Reading the comments, it seems to be the general consensus. [Nikolas Charalambidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764965/nikolas-charalambidis) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634866/how-can-i-form-a-string-containing-numbers-from-0-to-n/64734283?noredirect=1#comment114533256_64734283) that the solution could do with a `StringBuilder` instead:

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  s.append(i);
}
```

---

If you must use a `Stream`, I believe the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634919/12695027) is the way to go because

1. I think it just looks "clean" and
2. It also uses `StringBuilder` instead of `String`. There are other approaches though.

---

One approach is relying on side-effects. Create a variable and update it from within the stream. The JavaDoc on [Package java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) warns about the use:

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

```java
String[] alternativeWayA = {""};
IntStream.rangeClosed(0,n).forEach(i -> alternativeWayA[0] = alternativeWayA[0] + i);
```

---

[Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) mentions in one [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634866/how-can-i-form-a-string-containing-numbers-from-0-to-n#comment114284237_64634919)

> You could use `collect(Collectors.joining())` and have the same output

and in another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634866/how-can-i-form-a-string-containing-numbers-from-0-to-n#comment114284964_64634919)

> Well, you could use `boxed` before calling `collect`

```java
String alternativeWayB = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,n)
                                  .boxed()
                                  .map(i -> i.toString())
                                  .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

..if one prefers using `reduce` instead of `Collectors.joining`:

```java
String alternativeWayC = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,n)
                                  .boxed()
                                  .map(i -> i.toString())
                                  .reduce("", String::concat);
```

..or as [Nikolas Charalambidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764965/nikolas-charalambidis) suggests in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634866/how-can-i-form-a-string-containing-numbers-from-0-to-n#comment114284275_64634919)

> you need to `mapToObj` as this collector is not available for `IntStream`

```java
String alternativeWayD = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,n)
                                  .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                                  .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

---

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) posted a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634866/how-can-i-form-a-string-containing-numbers-from-0-to-n#comment114327413_64634919) with

> `String string = new String(IntStream.rangeClosed('1', '1'+n).toArray(), 0, n);`

which I think is very elegant and works for `n < 10`. For `n = 15` the result becomes `0123456789:;<=>?` since it's using integer values of characters. I added a `+ 1` to the last parameter of the `String` constructor:

```java
String alternativeWayE = new String(IntStream.rangeClosed('0', '0'+n).toArray(), 0, n + 1);
```

Comment: A nice summary! Finally, a for-loop with `StringBuilder` would be the best for me :) Have +1 for pointing out the *side-effects*.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Yes, of course :) I'm reluctant to add that though, since the Question is looking for a Stream implementation.

Comment: I feel it's no wrong to point that information out. However, with respect to the tags, the [java-stream] answer should be present (if such solution is possible, of course) with alternative ways to make the things better (a for-loop in such simple case).